# Vue.js display one data at a time from an array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My requirement is something like this

1. I have an array with few names.
2. I want to take first name from this array and display it inside the
   div. After that I want to display the second name then third...
3. I want this to happen as an infinite loop and names should be changed after a one minute of time.

How do I achieve this **using Vue.js**

```
<template>
  <div class="">

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      names:["Jona","Jane","Kalana"]
    }
  }


}
</script>
```

Comment: Checkout vue slider tutorials on the web, you can use same idea. And you should not ask a full solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to change the index of array at a fixed interval.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: "",
    names:["Jona","Jane","Kalana"]
  },
  computed: {
    namesLength: function() {
      return this.names.length;
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(()=>{
      const index = i++%this.namesLength;
      this.name = this.names[index];
    }, 3000); // Specify interval
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! =D and I also found a way to solve my problem. Again thanks a lot for helping me. =)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<template>
  <div class="">

{{toDisplay}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      names:["Jona","Jane","Kalana"],
      count:0,
      toDisplay:''
    }
  },
  methods:{
    
    onDisplay(){
      console.log("in")
      var self = this;
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        self.toDisplay = self.names[self.count];
        self.count = ++self.count;
        self.onDisplay();
        }, 3000);
        console.log("count",self.count)
        if(self.count >= this.names.length){
          self.count = 0;
        }
        
        
    }

  },
  created(){
    console.log("On created");
    this.onDisplay();
  }
  

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```